# Chunky PNG Image comparison- How to highlight multiple Differences

Tags: ruby, cucumber, chunkypng

I've just discovered [this article](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/comparing-images-and-creating-image-diffs/), which talks about comparing two images in Ruby and highlighting the differences.

But if I have images with multiple differences, e.g.: one difference is in the header and the other in the footer it will draw a rectangle on whole image.

Is it possible to draw a separate rectangle on each and every difference?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this chunky thing, but if you are looking for multiple image comparison with proper reporting of differences, you should look at a tool called Wraith which is also written in Ruby and is very very powerful for image comparison...
It is created by BBC_News and is open source.
https://github.com/BBC-News/wraith